# How to add a static object before dynamic data map in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I use [react-native-element-dropdown](https://github.com/hoaphantn7604/react-native-element-dropdown) package in my app.

I want to add dynamic data in the component. But first, I would like to add an empty dropdown option value like:

`{label: '-- Please Select --', value: ""}`

```
const dropdownData = () => {
    if(userList){
        return userList?.filter(user => user.id != null).map((user, index)=> {
            return {label: user.username, value: user.id}
        })
    }
}
```

The `dropdownData` is called in component's data property:

```
<Dropdown data={ dropdownData() } />
```

How can I add the empty value before the `userList` map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append your hard-coded option to the array before returning:

```
const dropdownData = () => {
    if (userList) {
        return [
            { label: '-- Please Select --', value: "" },
            ...userList
                .filter(user => user.id != null)
                .map(user => ({ label: user.username, value: user.id }))
        ];
    }
}
```

---

You can do the same in the JSX:

```
<Dropdown data={[ ...dropdownData(), { label: '-- Please Select --', value: "" } ]} />
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<Dropdown data={[{label: '-- Please Select --', value: ""}, ...dropdownData()]} />
```